# Windows: How do I lock the (remote) desktop from the command prompt?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Title says it all.

explorer isn't running so I can't grab the lock command from the start menu.

shutdown.exe doesn't seem to have any suitable option for it (shutdown -l is log off).

Windows-L would work on the local machine but gets grabbed by the local machine before it gets a chance to flow down RDP to the remote machine.

Should have a tag windows-core but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having not received any answers than the one by Art. Vandelay05, that is `rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation` that is a bad idea [Throwing garbage on the sidewalk: The sad history of the rundll32 program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/09/10208136.aspx), I've come to the conclusion there is no known good way.

Therefore I will deploy this C program:

```
#include <windows.h>
DWORD CALLBACK RawEntryPoint(void) { return !LockWorkStation(); }
```

Nice little program needing only kernel32.dll and user32.dll.

Answer (score 2):

Run the Win32 API [`LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx) function from the command prompt:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

<sup>Source: [Changing Computer State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/changing-computer-state) in PowerShell section of MSDN</sup>

**Note that this is officially unsupported** because `LockWorkStation` has a signature different from [the function signatures that `rundll32.exe` supports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface), which [leads to corruption of the process’s stack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043).

Since Windows Vista, `rundll32.exe` contains a [hack to contain reasonably small stack corruption and recover from it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683/). Still, this is not free license to abuse `rundll32`. Such abuse leads to similar hacks, which generally complicate things and would otherwise be unnecessary.

Use this at your own risk, or better not at all.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/09/10208136.aspx

Comment: I see.  I've used the above on Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 and the client equivalents.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I just used it yesterday to lock my remote session on one of our server 2012 r2 vms.  Think I should delete my answer?

Comment: Not yet. I may need to cite it. (Which is why I didn't down-vote it either.)